# Bool test on a string gives unexpected result

Tags: c#, boolean

This should be self explanatory. I am trying to detect if the first char of the string foo is a negative sign '-'. This is just a test code to test it.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string foo = textBox1.Text;
        bool negativeValue = foo[1]==('-');
        //bool negativeValue = foo[1].Equals ('-');

        if (negativeValue == true)
        {
            label1.Text = "First char is negative !";
        }

        else if (negativeValue == false)
        {
            label1.Text = "First char is not negative !";
        }
    }
```

The result is always false even if the first char in the text box is '-'. Why?

Comment: In a situation like this, you would have spotted the error easily by debugging the application, and looking up what value `foo[1]` has.

Comment: Recommended: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453.aspx and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong index.With `1` you are actually referring to 2nd character

Use `0`

```
 bool negativeValue = foo[0]==('-');
```

Comment: Thanks. No more wine for today!

Comment: In addition to the incorrect index being used, you can also use the more idiomatic `string.StartsWith` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Index lookup in C# is zero-based. So you should call:

```
foo[0] == ('-')
```

Using `1` will lookup the *second* character.

EDIT: Also as an alternative (and perhaps more clear) you can always use:

`foo.StartsWith("-")`

That should work no matter how inebriated you are. :)

(Also, consider trimming the text input if you want to avoid excessive/accidental preceding spaces from user input)

Comment: Oh man, Windows switched me over to _Canadian_ ÈEnglishÈ, let me switch it back.

Comment: There fixed. Seriously. I hate this crap. Because "Canadian _English_" really means "French" and just likes to (seemingly) randomly switch whenever it feels like it.

Comment: As I said, I stop drinking wine for today.